# Plone 5 Insufficient Privileges when writing Python script

Tags: python, plone

I am writing a Python script in Plone 5 to get contents of some pages of the website and coming across this error Insufficient Privileges when importing python libraries. Is there ay way to get around this?

Also, is there any way to use raw_input() python function here, because now it doesn't recognise the function?
Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/security/sandboxing.html  -- whatever you are doing is likely best not done in a restricted Python script.  Create an add-on and use a browser view instead ( http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/views/browserviews.html ).

Comment: Quick and dirty solution: Use an External Method http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/ScriptingZope.html#using-external-methods

Comment: Thanks, @avoinea! I am having trouble with creating an external method as  first of all, I do not have a Zope instance in my Plone folder to put the Extensions file in. I put Extensions in Plone/zinstance but whenI add an External method, it says the page does not seem to exist. What could be wrong?

Comment: I have been able to create an External method, problem solved,thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So there is an answer...

Through the web Python Scripts run a sandboxed python interpreter and throw unauthorized errors when you try to import potentially unsafe code.

See http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/security/sandboxing.html